# iPhone NSString

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I just wanted to know how i can determine whether a NSString string has a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[NSNumberFormatter numberFromString: s];` and it will return nil if it is not a number.

```
NSString *s = @"2.5";

NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber * num = [formatter numberFromString:s];
[formatter release];
```

If `num` is `nil` it is not a number.

Link to docs on [NSNumberFormatterStyle](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setNumberStyle%3a)

Comment: Did you mean `s` instead of `@s`?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s `numberFromString:` method.

Comment: i know that however not getting any help, can u help with small code

Comment: No. You call it on an NSString and check that the result is not nil.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a string has a number or not by using regex

```
    NSString *search = @"23.3";
    //regex for integer number ->   ^[0-9]*$
    //regex for integer and decimal number ->    ^[0-9]+([\,\.][0-9]+)?$
    NSString *pattern = @"(^[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?$)";
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:search options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, search.length)];

    if(match == nil){
        NSLog(@"Not a number");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Number");
    }
```